# I cannot write information to a filesystem file from my newly installed MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, filestream

Hello and thank you for your help.    I must write non-tabular information to a file.   I have tried a few methods that invoke various stored procedures.   The following SQL statement tests this and I don't know how to make it work.   I have evaluated and set permission for the MSSQLSERVER user on the directory.    Would someone help me please?

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE @FileSystem INT;
DECLARE @FileHandle INT;
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @ForWriting INT;
DECLARE @CreateIfNeeded INT;
DECLARE @TextStream INT;
DECLARE @TextToWrite VARCHAR(MAX);

-- Set the file path
SET @FilePath = 'C:\Users\crmcw\AppData\Local';
SET @ForWriting = 2; -- Constant for write mode
SET @CreateIfNeeded = 8; -- Constant to create the file if it doesn't exist

-- Create the FileSystemObject
EXEC sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FileSystem OUT;

-- Open the file using the OpenTextFile method
EXEC sp_OAMethod @FileSystem, 'OpenTextFile', @FileHandle OUT, @FilePath, @ForWriting, @CreateIfNeeded;

-- Check if the file handle was successfully obtained
IF @FileHandle <> 0
BEGIN
    -- File handle obtained, proceed with writing to the file
    SET @TextToWrite = 'This is the text to write to the file.';

    -- Write the text to the file
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @FileHandle, 'WriteLine', NULL, @TextToWrite;

    -- Close the file
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @FileHandle, 'Close';

    -- Clean up the COM objects
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @FileHandle;
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @FileSystem;

    PRINT 'File created and written successfully.';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- File handle not obtained, there was an error
    PRINT 'Failed to create or open the file.';
END
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you see an error?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don't use `sp_OA` procedures, they are ancient and full of bugs and are difficult to use correctly. Instead use a proper scripting language like Powershell (you can even create a SQL Agent job written in Powershell). This whole procedure is a single line of Powershell.

Comment: Thank you Martin.   I did indeed.   I set the EXEC to a variable and evaluated it thus:

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface.    I haven't used MS SQL for about 30 years.   This is very helpful.

Comment: In Powershell you could do `$TestToWrite | Out-Content -FilePath $FilePath;` As a side note: I see two problems with your code. The file path is actually a directory. You can't write to a directory, you need an actual file path to write to. And SQL Server is unlikely to have the correct permissions to write to a user's private folder, as it runs under a separate service account.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface.     Looks like I have to do my homework.    I appreciate the help.